# Shorten column names, provide tooltip on hover of full name

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a `datatable` that I'm displaying within a simple R Shiny app. I have many long column names that prevent me from maximally using the horizontal screen space. I would like to do two things:

1. Abbreviate or truncate each column name so that each column is skinny (compared to the current state, see MRE below). Ideally, I would like each column to be only as wide as the cell which contains the longest string of data (e.g. in column 1, below, the column width should be no wider than the amount of space that 'AAAAA' occupies) . By default, `datatable` tables look quite chunky, and they don't make maximal use of screen real estate.
2. On hovering over the abbreviated/truncated column name, the user is presented with the full-length name.

```
x<-data.frame(a_long_column_name = c("AAAAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC"), 
              a_really_unnecessarily_long_column_name = c("Alice", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob", "Charlie"),
              a_silly_and_unnecessarily_long_column_name_which_i_cant_change = c("T-Shirt", "Pants", "Socks", "Socks", "Pants", "T-Shirt"),
              another_silly_and_unnecessarily_long_column_name_which_i_cant_change = c("Red", "Orange", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Yellow"))


library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

runApp(list(

  ui = basicPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
      x<-datatable(x, selection = "single", filter = "top")
    })
  }
))
```

I believe it's possible to abbreviate column names with base `abbreviate()` for example:

```
colnames(x) <- sapply(names(x), function(x) abbreviate(x, minlength = 16))
```

but the abbreviations become mostly unreadable and I still can't figure out how to implement the hover functionality as outlined in Point 2, above.

I think the best solution might be to truncate each column name by x number of characters (e.g. if x = 12 then Column 1 becomes 'a_long_colum...' and Column 2 would become 'a_really_unn...')

At this point I'm open to any and all ideas/solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with a `headerCallback`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(glue) # for easier text concatenation

x <- data.frame(a_long_column_name = c("AAAAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC"), 
                a_really_unnecessarily_long_column_name = c("Alice", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob", "Charlie"),
                a_silly_and_unnecessarily_long_column_name_which_i_cant_change = c("T-Shirt", "Pants", "Socks", "Socks", "Pants", "T-Shirt"),
                another_silly_and_unnecessarily_long_column_name_which_i_cant_change = c("Red", "Orange", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Yellow"))

headerCallback <- c(
  "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  sprintf("  var tooltips = [%s];", toString(paste0("'", colnames(x), "'"))),
  "  for(var i = 1; i <= tooltips.length; i++){",
  "    $('th:eq('+i+')',thead).attr('title', tooltips[i-1]);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

runApp(list(

  ui = basicPage(
    DTOutput('mytable')
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDT({
      datatable(
        x, 
        selection = "single", 
        filter = "top",
        colnames = glue(
          "{substr(colnames(x),1,5)}..."
        ),
        options = list(
          headerCallback= JS(headerCallback)
        )
      )
    })
  }
))
```

---

## EDIT

Here is a solution using the [qTip2 library](http://qtip2.com/demos).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(glue) # for easier text concatenation

x <- data.frame(a_long_column_name = c("AAAAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC"), 
                a_really_unnecessarily_long_column_name = c("Alice", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob", "Charlie"),
                a_silly_and_unnecessarily_long_column_name_which_i_cant_change = c("T-Shirt", "Pants", "Socks", "Socks", "Pants", "T-Shirt"),
                another_silly_and_unnecessarily_long_column_name_which_i_cant_change = c("Red", "Orange", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Yellow"))

qTips <- function(titles){
  settings <- sprintf(paste(
    "{",
    "  content: {",
    "    text: '%s'",
    "  },",
    "  show: {",
    "    ready: false",
    "  },",
    "  position: {",
    "    my: 'bottom %%s',",
    "    at: 'center center'",
    "  },",
    "  style: {",
    "    classes: 'qtip-youtube'",
    "  }",
    "}",
    sep = "\n"
  ), titles)
  n <- length(titles)
  settings <- sprintf(settings, ifelse(1:n > n/2, "right", "left"))
  sprintf("var tooltips = [%s];", paste0(settings, collapse=","))
}

headerCallback <- c(
  "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  qTips(colnames(x)),
  "  for(var i = 1; i <= tooltips.length; i++){",
  "    $('th:eq('+i+')',thead).qtip(tooltips[i-1]);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

runApp(list(

  ui = basicPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.css"), 
      tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.js")
    ),
    br(),
    DTOutput('mytable')
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDT({
      datatable(
        x, 
        selection = "single", 
        filter = "top",
        colnames = glue("{substr(colnames(x),1,5)}..."),
        options = list(
          headerCallback= JS(headerCallback)
        )
      )
    })
  }
))
```

[image]

These tooltips are customizable by setting the `style.classes` attribute. For example use this CSS:

```
           .myqtip { 
             font-size: 15px;
             line-height: 18px;
             background-color: rgb(245,245,245,0.8);
             border-color: rgb(54,57,64);
           }
```

and set `classes: 'myqtip'` instead of `classes: 'qtip-youtube'`. See the website for demos. You can also change the position, set a hide effect, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the aesthetics of the pop up using this solution?

Comment: @Simon No I don't think so, these are basic tooltips. I have an app in which I use the JavaScript `qTip2` library for the header tooltips, and these tooltips are highly customizable.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive edit to your answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can use any methods for abbreviating the column names as long as it makes sense to you.

To create tooltips, you need to convert column name text to HTML and add `title`, `data-toggle` attributes to be used in callback.

The callback uses bootstrap tooltips.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(glue) # for easier text concatenation

runApp(list(

    ui = basicPage(
        tags$head(
            tags$style(
                # this line is added because some column names are way too long
                # and the default max width of tooltip cannot contain them
                ".tooltip-inner {max-width: 500px; /* the minimum width */}" 
            )
        ),
        DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
    ),

    server = function(input, output) {
        output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
            x<-datatable(
                x, 
                selection = "single", 
                filter = "top",
                # title is the content displayed in tooltip
                # data-toggle='tooltip' is used as selector in callback function
                # Now I'm using first 5 characters and ... as default column names, but you're free to use other abbreviation methods
                colnames = glue(
                    "<span title={colnames(x)} data-toggle='tooltip'>{substr(colnames(x),1,5)}...</span>"
                ),
                # bind pop-up to table headers
                callback = JS("$('#mytable').tooltip({selector:'[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]'})"),
                # parse content as HTML(don't escape)
                escape = FALSE
            )
        })
    }
))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Accepting this because I prefer the aesthetics of the tooltip. Final thing - are you able to point me in the right direction for further customising the look of the tooltip? e.g. larger font, different background colour etc.

Comment: Because it uses bootstrap 3 tooltips. You can read documentations on it or search for relevant questions. One source could be W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction (I didn't know they were called Bootstrap Tooltips).